How to render child object separately from parent Unity3D?
For example if I have a fully rigged 3D humanoid model, how would I only render the “LeftHand” and “RightHand” of that model in game view so that the rest of the player is not visible to me (but is visible to others)?
I have tried several methods. I tried using two cameras, one to render only the Player, and the other to render Hands, using culling masks, depth and so on. This didn’t work I think because of the hands being child objects of the model.
I also tried going into Blender, editing vertexes of the hands and then duplicating them, so that I get Alpha_Joints001 and 002. When importing into Unity, the hands would not move at all and would not mimic my inverse kinematics or any simple animations.
I know there’s a method to do with creating a custom shader but I would not know where to start with that. Is it not possible to just use layers to somehow disconnect the hands from the rest of the model despite being child objects of it? I have the entire Player mesh set to “Player” layer, including the parent. However I changed the layers of both hands and fingers to “Hands”. This hasn’t done anything though.
My hierarchy is:
Player (empty GameObject, parent)
    → RiggedModelMesh (child of Player, this is my imported rigged humanoid character)
    → Alpha_Joints, Alpha_Surface (child of RiggedModelMesh)
    → All the bones such as hips, leftleg, rightleg, spine, neck, etc (child of RiggedModelMesh)


Use another layer for your hands, and display that one layer on your POV/Ego camera and disable the rest of the other object again using layers.

My bad if I'm misreading it, but is this basically what I already attempted? Having two cameras, one to render only my hands, and my other camera (main cam) which hides the rest of the player mesh? The problem is that the hands are children objects of the player mesh so this method doesn't seem to work

As a simple solution, you can use two separate instances of your character. A bit more complex one would be to only copy the character mesh in Unity, so you have two meshes alongside each other under Player. If I remember correctly, you then need to create a script to store the bones of the original into the new copy (can be done in Editor). The solution with hands as a separate mesh is also viable, but implies some learning curve of how to do it properly in blender. Probably some tutorials how changeable clothes are done can be of help here.

Btw, what do you need that for? Local multiplayer? Mirrors? Reflection? Shadows? Just in case, this is not needed for networked multiplayer.

@Vladimir thanks for the reply. I'm going to test out your solution, however to answer your question, I spent months implementing my own functioning recoil system for first person. I have realistic bullets (gravity, velocity, etc), and I have my fully modeled and rigged weapons, and now I need to implement animations.

@Vladimir And in most fps games, when you look down at your feet, your entire body is invisible. Only your hands plus weapon are visible. However, other players can see your entire body, hands and weapon, if that makes sense. I'm trying to find a way to only render my hands and weapon, but have the rest of my body be invisible. Currently, if I look down, sometimes my camera clips into my body/head, even though the camera is positioned correctly by default.

@Vladimir just as a quick follow up, since there's no online tutorials on this, I can't tell if I did it correctly, but I believe I already tried the approach of duplicating my hands mesh inside of Blender then re-importing the 3d player model into unity and trying that. however the hands wouldn't work with any of my animation rigging/inverse kinematics

If you use the two layers approach it shouldn't matter that the hands are children of other objects .. that's not even unusual. Are you sure you put only the hands on the layer and not the entire player mesh hierarchy?

@derHugo Yeah I made sure. I have a 3D rigged player model (set as humanoid). It has a bunch of children objects: lefthips, spine, neck, righthips, lefthand, leftindex, etc. It also has two objects alpha_joints and alpha_surface both with skinnedmeshrenderers. I set the "Right Hand" and "Left Hand" (including the hands children objects aka fingers) all to "Hands" layer. The rest of the mesh is on "Player" layer. This doesn't seem to work though.

Also, the 3D player model mesh is a child of my "Player" object which is just an empty object that has my character controller component (Also has the "Player" layer). I'm also using the Unity3D Animation Rigging package so maybe my use of "Rig" components + "Rig Layer" etc is affecting it? Not sure.

@dangoqut132 "However, other players can see your entire body, hands and weapon, if that makes sense. " In online multiplayer, other players don't see what is rendered on your machine. They see what is rendered on their machines. In other words, you render only two hands for local player and only full body for remote players.

What I woud worry about in that case are shadows and reflections if you only render hands. Shadows have the following workaround: instead of removing the body, divide it's material into parts (there's a paid FPS Mesh Tool on the asset store that automates this process). Then use an invisible material for everything except hands, but still keep everything as shadow casters. For reflections, the simplest solution is to exclude the character completely. Or you can use a copy of the full body with original materials, in which case you will need to make it follow the animations.

As of tutorials, you can watch tutorials on clothing. Not sure how good this one is, but what you ask for is exactly what clothing is: a separate mesh under same root that is animated with the main skeleton.

"I set the "Right Hand" and "Left Hand" (including the hands children objects aka fingers) all to "Hands" layer. " "Right Hand" and "Left Hand" should be separate skinned mesh renderers containing hands in order for that to work. If they are just bones, setting them to a different layer won't solve the issue as bones are just bones, they don't render anything.
